# .NET - What is a proper way of interacting with a worker from console?

Tags: c#, .net, console, worker

I have a worker written in .Net 5.0 which runs in background. In the same time, I have another (console) project with a CLI.

How do I implement interaction between worker and console client? I imagine a case when the worker has some services, which are using a connection to the database for example, and while it performs its regular tasks, I want him to respond if I enter a command that will call some of its' services (e.g. potentially change something in the database - fetch some info, or update anything etc.)

As far as I have searched, the only option will be opening a socket but isn't that a bit overkill?

Comment: 1) no, it's not overkill. you could probably implement it in less time than you've spent researching alternatives 2) write something in a file that's regularly checked, or a database table, if you don't want to use a socket

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thank you! I have found many various libraries such as NetCoreServer or SockNet, could you advice which is better for these kind of things? I know that SignalR is the most popular but for the websockets.